# unexpected exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to use the following code to test "set_unexpected()". I expect the code will generate an output like:

```
In function f(), throw const char* object
Call to my_unexpected
Exception in main(): Exception thrown from my_unexpected
```

But I got a run-time error: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way." So, what would be the problem? Thanks

```
struct E {
  const char* message;
  E(const char* arg) : message(arg) { }
};

void my_unexpected() {
  cout << "Call to my_unexpected" << endl;
  throw E("Exception thrown from my_unexpected");
}

void f() throw(E) {
  cout << "In function f(), throw const char* object" << endl;
  throw("Exception, type const char*, thrown from f()");
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
      set_unexpected(my_unexpected);
  try {
    f();
  }
  catch (E& e) {
    cout << "Exception in main(): " << e.message << endl;
  }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In my understanding you didn't do anything wrong (and g++ [has no problem](http://ideone.com/jpHqd) with this code); maybe it's a bug of the compiler? (by the way, exception specifications are generally a bad idea, you should probably avoid them in "real" code)

Comment: Shouldn't `throw("Exception, type const char*, thrown from f()");` be
`throw "Exception, type const char*, thrown from f()";`?

Comment: @mydogisbox: it shouldn't make any difference, he's just putting a `const char *` inside parentheses.

Comment: This works for me (using G++ 3.4.5 on MinGW). Perhaps there is something wrong with the way your console output is handled? The `_tmain` function (instead of just `main`) suggests that you are using some kind of runtime library.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008. I guess it's the compiler. I will try g++ later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C++ does not implement correctly exception specifications. As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx),

> Visual C++ departs from the ANSI Standard in its implementation of exception specifications.

and in particular

> `throw(type)` - The function can throw an exception of type type. However, in Visual C++ .NET, this is interpreted as `throw(...)`.

Also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skce93f2.aspx):

> Function exception specifiers other than `throw()` are parsed but not used.

Because of this, your `terminate` handler is never called, and since no handlers for `const char *` are present in your code the exception is not caught and the application terminates abnormally.

---

Anyway, keep in mind that exception specifications different from `throw()` are [generally considered a bad idea](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm), and actually the new C++ standard (C++11) deprecates them, introducing `noexcept` for what `throw()` was used.